# PHPUnit code coverage through Guzzle

Tags: php, phpunit, guzzle

We've got PHPUnit 4.8 and GuzzleHttp 5.3 setup and running, allowing us to test our API endpoints with unit-test style coding.

This all works fine. We're also generating clover reports and HTML reports using the inbuilt PHPUnit style. Again, this is working.

However, code coverage doesn't seem to be picking up the code that is run when the HTTP endpoints are called.

Is there anyway to address this? Is it possible to get code coverage based on a call to a HTTP endpoint?

Cheers

Comment: The normal way to increase code coverage is to write more tests that make code execution use the code that is currently not being covered.

Comment: That is what's happening. The code in question is an API, the unit tests call the API and use PHPUnit and GuzzleHttp - I'd like to get the code coverage report from that.

Comment: Do you mean you want code coverage from the code that is run in the API that you are calling?

Comment: Have the same question, I think. Yes, I want code executed because of the guzzle api request to "count" toward code coverage. Possible this is an xdebug issue more than a phpunit one?